# How can I have an input form fill the entire table data cell but not expand the width of the entire row?

Tags: php, html, css, html-table

I want to have a row of text inputs at the bottom of my table, whose sizes are the same as the widest element in their row. When I set width:100%, it expands the width of the whole row, which I do not want.
My CSS:

```
table,th,td{
    border-style: solid; 
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-color:black;
    background-color: var(--background);
    border-width: 3px;

}
th{
    background-color: var(--accent1);
    color:white;
    padding:0px 10px;
}
td{
    background-color:white;
    color:black;
    padding:0px 10px;
}
#centeredTd{
    text-align: center;
}
#inputRow td input{
    width:100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#endTable{
    border-color:var(--background);
}

.textEntry{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    color:var(--normal);
    background-color:var(--background);
    border-color:var(--normal);
    width:140px;
    border-radius:5px;
    border-width: 2px;
}
```

My PHP/HTML

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM `players`");
echo"<table><tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Grade</th><th>Target</th><th>Hunter</th><th>Kills</th><th></th></tr>";


while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo"<tr><td>{$data['firstname']}</td><td>{$data['lastname']}</td><td>{$data['email']}</td><td id='centeredTd'>{$data['grade']}</td><td>{$data['target']}</td><td>{$data['hunter']}</td><td id='centeredTd'>{$data['killcount']}</td><td>
    <form action='' method='post'>
        <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$data['id']."'>
        <input type='submit' class='submit' id='rm' value='-' name='remove'>
    </form>
    </td></tr>";
}
echo"
    <form action='./' method='post'>
        <tr id='inputRow'>
        <td><input type='text' name='firstname' class='textEntry'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='lastname' class='textEntry'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='email' class='textEntry' id='emailEntry'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='grade' class='textEntry' id='gradeEntry'></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
        <td><input type='submit' value='+' class='submit' id='rm'></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
";
echo"</table>";
```

I also have formatting for my normal text input fields but I think that should be overridden.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML text inputs have a `size` attribute in HTML, specifying the number of characters wide the input should be. The default value is 20. I found that by setting the size to a small number (`size='3'`), inputs styled with `width: 100%;` behave as you want them to – they take on the width of the column they are in.

This snippet demonstrates the effect. Note that you may need to view it **full page** to see the difference.

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}
th, td {
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
th {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.centered {
    text-align: center;
}
.inputRow input {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-width: 2px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p>In this table, the inputs have a <strong>small specified size</strong></p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Grade</th>
    <th>Target</th>
    <th>Hunter</th>
    <th>Kills</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Gus</td>
    <td>Christodoulopoulos</td>
    <td>gus@olivemail.gr</td>
    <td class='centered'>AAA</td>
    <td>Desdemona</td>
    <td>Konstantinos</td>
    <td class='centered'>999</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Theophilus</td>
    <td>Mastromihalis</td>
    <td>theo@gyromail.gr</td>
    <td class='centered'>AB-</td>
    <td>Magdalena</td>
    <td>Philadelphia</td>
    <td class='centered'>2</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='inputRow'>
    <td><input type='text' name='firstname' size='3'></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='lastname' size='3'></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='email' size='3' id='emailEntry'></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='grade' size='3' id='gradeEntry'></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type='submit' value='+' class='submit' id='rm'></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>And for comparison, in this table, the inputs don't have a specified size. You may need to view this snippet full screen to see the difference.</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Grade</th>
    <th>Target</th>
    <th>Hunter</th>
    <th>Kills</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Gus</td>
    <td>Christodoulopoulos</td>
    <td>gus@olivemail.gr</td>
    <td class='centered'>AAA</td>
    <td>Desdemona</td>
    <td>Konstantinos</td>
    <td class='centered'>999</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Theophilus</td>
    <td>Mastromihalis</td>
    <td>theo@gyromail.gr</td>
    <td class='centered'>AB-</td>
    <td>Magdalena</td>
    <td>Philadelphia</td>
    <td class='centered'>2</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='inputRow'>
    <td><input type='text' name='firstname'></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='lastname'></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='email' id='emailEntry'></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='grade' id='gradeEntry'></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type='submit' value='+' class='submit' id='rm'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you know if I can specify this using CSS rather than doing it each time in HTML?